# how to preserve the effect of onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers

I want to show the base map when the page loaded. So I added the base map as follows:

```
<body onload="init()">
```

init() has the logic to display the base map.

After clicking on submit button in the page, I want to impose a layer on that map. That logic I have written in a function called onSubmit:

```
<form onsubmit="onSubmit()">
```

But what is happening that after submitting the form, page is again loaded and init() is called again and as a result I am getting the base map again :(

please suggest.

Comment: You need to prevent the submit event - `<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); onSubmit()">`

Comment: Is it a requirement that you submit the form or do you merely need to send a value to OpenLayers client side?

Answer (score 2):

**If you need the to submit the page:**

In the `onSubmit()` event, send a flag to the server which states that this event called. For instance, call  it `submitExecuted`. Then, when the `init()` is called, retrieve this flag from the server and do not show the map.

I don't know which tecnology you're using on the server side, but you can persist this flag either in a page-scoped variable (for ASP.NET use view state) or save it in the session, if you have no other option.

**If you don't need to submit the page:**

instead of calling `onSubmit()`, call `return onSubmit();` and make the `onSubmit()` method return false.